# Nvidia layout inconsistencies when saving to x configuration file (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, configuration, nvidia-settings

I am having trouble saving to the x config file from the nvidia x server settings. When I click the "Save to X Configuration File" button, I get "The current layout has some inconsistencies". Under Show Details it says "MetaMode 1 of Screen 0  does not have an active display device". I have been trying to edit the resolution of my second monitor(I'm using a laptop) and I believe this is getting in the way. Does anyone know what this means and how I can fix it?